# How to show an element in Jquery after 1 seconds only if the mouse is still over the element?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to create a hover-menu inside a gridview like the one of Gmail when you put the mouse over the names in the chatlist.

How to show an element in Jquery after 1-2 seconds **only if the mouse is still over the element**?

The following is not working properly because if i just move the mouse throughout the list, all the elements will show up (even though with a delay of 1 sec.)

```
 $('.label, .popup').hover(function(e) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".popup").show();
                }, 1000);


            }, function(e) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".popup").hide();
                }, 1000);
            });

<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Label ID="label1" CssClass="label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column1") %>'></asp:Label>

            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="popup" CssClass="popup" 
            Style="display: none; position: absolute; margin-left: 60px; width: 250px;">


                Random text

            </asp:Panel>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/eydMC/3/ ?

Comment: ...or this http://jsfiddle.net/JYuKC/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the setTimeoutin the mouseout function, so if 1 second hasn't passed since mouse over the element isn't shown.

```
$('.label, .popup').hover(function(e) {
            $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout(function() {
                $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".popup").show();
            }, 1000));


        }, function(e) {
            clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".popup").hide();
            }, 1000);
        });
```